# How to share dynamic contents like images, URL, descriptions, and title on Facebook

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, facebook

I have data in my database like images, titles, and their descriptions.
I have displayed this information in divs such that each div contains a title image and a description.

And now my task is to share this on Facebook, because each div has its own URL. currently I am using PHP and jQuery.

When I click the share button the share dialog box appears, but then it comes with Facebook defaults, like "Facebook developer documentation title".

Below is my markup inside `<head>`:

```
<title><?php echo $postin_title2;?></title>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://shefil.com/php/fully.php?p=<?php echo $page_ID;?>" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $postin_title2;?>" />
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo$description;?>"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.test.com/uploads/<?php echo $i_image ;?>" />
```

And below is my share button which when clicked runs a function:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="fb_share(<?php echo $postin_title2;?>,<?php echo $postin_title2;?>,<?php echo $description;?>)" ><img class="shiring" title="Share on Facebook" alt="Share on Facebook" src="../icons/color/Facebook.png"></a></li>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script lazy_load="false" type="text/javascript">
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
    appId            : 'my app id',
    autoLogAppEvents : true,
    xfbml            : true,
    version          : 'v2.10'
  });
  FB.AppEvents.logPageView();
};

(function(d, s, id){
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function fb_share(dynamic_link,dynamic_title,dynamic_content) {
  var app_id = '000000000000000';
  var pageURL="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=" + app_id + "&link=" + dynamic_link;
  var w = 600;
  var h = 400;
  var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
  var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
  window.open(pageURL, dynamic_title, dynamic_content, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=yes, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + 800 + ', height=' + 650 + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
  return false;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Please tell us where the problem is or what the results does now and what it should look like/behave.

Comment: ok first sorry for any inconveniences when i click the share button the share dialog box appears but then comes with facebook defaults like "facebook developer documentation title"

Comment: what does `console.log(dynamic_title);` inside ` fb_share()` print in the browser console? Does the button (the a inside the li) have the right text inside the onclick attribute?